# How to use FontAwesome on fxml JavaFX without Maven

Tags: java, javafx-8, font-awesome, fxml

I'm using fontawesomefx-8.9 because I couldn't find a tutorial for adding a newer version to the project(I don't even know how to download it from Bintray).
The problem is when I add an icon it shows up like [an empty rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giIzd.png). I've added the library to both SceneBuilder and the project library. I've tried changing the IDE but it's the same.

Here is the [project](https://github.com/esttueb/Recetario3/tree/master/src/recetario), I'm still learning Java btw.

Comment: Have you designated your controls to use FontAwesome inside your CSS?

Comment: @SilverMonkey I've tried but it didn't work, I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: If you define keys in a property file, which refer to the respective unicode of the icon you want to use, you can simply assign it in fxml.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maven uses [The Central Repository](https://search.maven.org) to download dependency automatically for you from there. I would recommend you to embrace [maven or another dependency management tool](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-build-tools-how-dependency-management-works-with-maven-gradle-and-ant-ivy/) for java. It will makes you life way easier.

But if you can't use dependency management. For some reason unknown to me. You still can download jars manually from the central repository. In your case choose [any published version of fontawesomefx](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.jensd%22%20AND%20a%3A%22fontawesomefx%22), download the jar(s) and add them to your project's classpath.

Comment: I can't move my project to a Maven one, I always get some kind of error that I can't fix. I'll be thankful if you explain me how to do it. I've tried doing it with Intellij and with NetBeans